# JSF Managed Bean Code Assist Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, autocomplete

Is there a way within Eclipse (MyEclipse specifically) to have code assist functionality within a JSF (or XHTML, or JSP, etc) file where I am attempting to access managed bean properties?

See section 8.1.2.1.2.2. Content Assist Based on Project Data @ http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.0.0.GA/jsf/en/html/jbds_editors.html for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs you referenced are a perfect way to achieve way you need. Contrary to what its name may suggest, JBossTools is universally useable without the need to deploy to JBoss or otherwise have any JBoss specific things in your code.

The only thing is that MyEclipse, being a massively modified Eclipse, will probably not work together with JBossTools (but actually it is supposed to offer exactly this kind of functionality already).

Comment: It doesn't appear that MyEclipse has this built in.  I will explore it further.  Unfortunately, I am not able to use the JBossTools directly.

Comment: Accepted this answer more because there apparently is no documented way to create the behavior I am interested in without access to additional IDEs or plugins. Thanks